# where can I find the Dell Wireless WLAN Card Utility

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm having trouble finding the Dell Wireless utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download it, it's here:

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?fileid=187881